# How to access a method from another if it has arguments

Tags: java, methods

I want to know how I can access a call a method when it has an arraylist as an argument from an another class.

```
import java.util.*;
class Business
{
public static void main()
{
    Scanner si = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter--");
    System.out.println("1 to add a account");
    System.out.println("2 to check the balance");
    int d = si.nextInt();
    if(d==1)
    {
        add_account();
    }
    if(d == 2)
    {
        check();
    }
    
}
public static void add_account()
{
    Scanner si = new Scanner(System.in);
    int min = 1000;
    int max = 9999;
    int acn;
    List<Double> ac = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> cl = new ArrayList<>(); 
    List<String> al = new ArrayList<>(); 
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the account user");
    al.add(si.next());
    System.out.println("Enter the amount user has deposited");
    cl.add(si.nextInt());
    ac.add(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min));
    System.out.println("Please re-enter your name");
    String name = si.next();
    acn = al.indexOf(name);
    System.out.println("Your account number is "+acn);
    System.out.println("Your account password is "+ac.get(acn));
    System.out.println(ac);
    main();
}
public static void check(List<Double> ac)
{
    Scanner si = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the account number whoose you want to check the balance");
    int c = si.nextInt();
    System.out.println(ac);
}
}
```

Here, I want to know how to access the check method, I think I have to write in something in the brackets . If so, can you tell me what to write, if not please tell how can I access the check method from the main method.

Comment: Does this link help you? [Java method parameters](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_methods_param.asp)

Comment: *I think I have to write in something in the brackets* is the right assumption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to move the 3 lists storing the user data from the `add_account` to the class level as static variables like this:

```
public class Business {
    private static List<Double> ac = new ArrayList<>();
    private static List<Integer> cl = new ArrayList<>();
    private static List<String> al = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main() {
    //...
    }
    public static void add_account() {
    //...
    }

    public static void check() {
    //...
    }
}
```

This way you can remove the input parameter from the `check` method and just access the class level `ac` list.

However a better solution would be to model the account as dedicated class like

```
public class Account {
    String name;
    Integer balance;
    String password;
    // getters + setters
}
```

and store them in a Map where the key is the accounts name/id

```
private static Map<String, Account> accounts = new HashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to understand the code

```
public static void check(List<Double> ac)
{
    Scanner si = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the account number whoose you want to check the balance");
    int c = si.nextInt();
    System.out.println(ac);
}
```

here you declare the method with a parameter of a List. So you cannot call this method without giving a parameter inside. If you want to search the account inside of the method, you can just remove the parameter of the method, get the account and display it.

```
public static void check() //parameter removed
{
    Scanner si = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the account number whoose you want to check the balance");
    int c = si.nextInt();  // get the account number
     List<Double> account = new ArrayList<Double>();
      // ... some operation 
    System.out.println(account.toString());
}
```

After that inside of the main method, you can call this method

```
public static void main()
{
    Scanner si = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter--");
    System.out.println("1 to add a account");
    System.out.println("2 to check the balance");
    int d = si.nextInt();
    if(d==1)
    {
        add_account();
    }
    if(d == 2)
    {
        check();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: ``List<Double> list = new List<>(); Business.check(list);`` A list is used the same as any other parameter.